# How to solve this bug in listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm making a file manager for android, but I'm having a problem displaying files and folders in the listview. I'm getting repeated folder and file names, but when I click to proceed in the folder, the ArrayList returns the name correctly. My code:

```
public void loadFiles(String path){
       listmap.clear();
       array.clear();
       FileUtil.listDir(path, array);
       int position = 0;
       String currentlyPath = path;
       text_currently_path.setText(currentlyPath);
       for(int rep=0; rep< (int)(array.size()); rep++){
           {
           HashMap<String, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
           item.put("path", array.get(position));
           listmap.add(item);
           }
           position++;
           listview_files.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(listmap));
       }
   }
```

I want to know if it's possible to fix this. Thanks a lot to anyone who answers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely is that the ListView adapter recycles the item views, but does not re-initializes them for some reason. This is why you see repeated files and folders: the item views show file names that went outside of the visible part of the list, and are beign incorrectly reused for representing another file.